# WP8 change background image when button clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, background-image

When a button is clicked, I want to change the background image in the mainpage. In the xaml I have ; `Style="{StaticResource LayoutGridStyle}`for background. How can I achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
    {
        public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object resourceKey)
        {
            var currentElement = element;

            while (currentElement != null)
            {
                var resource = currentElement.Resources[resourceKey];
                if (resource != null)
                {
                    return resource;
                }

                currentElement = currentElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            }

            return Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey];
        }
    }

        private void PageTitle_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationTitle.Style = (Style)ApplicationTitle.TryFindResource("PhoneTextTitle1Style");
        }
```

sample is given  [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31216763/PhoneApp1.rar)

Answer (score 0):

Include the style or background image (however you want to handle it) as a property in your ViewModel for the mainpage. Then bind to this...

```
Style="{Binding NameOFViewModelProperty}
```

The when you change the style through the button clicked code make sure you raise a property changed event...

```
RaisePropertyChanged("NameOFViewModelProperty");
```

so the page knows to refresh itself with the changes.